# Display the JSON data in parent-child hierarchical structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

We want to display the JSON data in parent-child hierarchical structure

```
var JsonArr = [{
                   "comment":"Comment 1", 
                   "commentID":1, 
                   "parentID":0,
                   "children":[{
                              "comment":"Comment 1-2", 
                              "commentID":2, 
                              "parentID":1, 
                              "children":[{
                                         "comment":"Comment 1-2-2",
                                         "commentID":1,
                                         "parentID":2 
                                         }]
                            }]
                },
                {
                "comment":"Comment 2", 
                "commentID":4, 
                "parentID":0
               }]
```

**Current Output :**
[image]

**Expected Output :**
[image]

Working JSFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/6dcdbks4/

Any Immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgupggnz/).

not exactly a `tree` structure but we can mimic it using `css` and passing passing `level` information

```
function showComments(comments,level){//Extra parameter for level information
 for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
     commentsContainer = loadComment(comments[i], commentsContainer,level)//render comment along with level information
    if (comments[i]['children'] && comments[i]['children'].length) {
      showComments(comments[i]['children'],level+1)//next level for children
    }
  }
}

function loadComment(commentObj, commentsContainer,level){//level of node
    var profileFullName = "Full Name";
    //add some padding multiplied with level for each comment element
    var commentHTML = '<div class="commentbox" style="padding-left:'+(level*100)+'px;"><div class="commentphoto"><a href="#123"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100000816365798/picture?type=square"></a></div><div class="commentcontent"><a href="#123"><strong>' + profileFullName + '</strong></a> &nbsp;<small>Just now</small><br>' + commentObj.comment + '<br><a name="replyComment" commentid="' + commentObj.commentID + '">Reply</a><span id="votescore-' + commentObj.commentID + '" class="votescore"></span></div></div>';
    commentsContainer.append(commentHTML);
    return commentsContainer;
}

showComments(JsonArr,0);//call showComment with initial level 0
```

Comment: I updated your fiddle..i changed the json and its not working. https://jsfiddle.net/jgupggnz/2/

Comment: can you check the data one more time?`Comment 1-2` you kept two 'children' arrays

Comment: yes..it is a possiblity to have two children of same parent.

Comment: but thats not right.if you have multiple children why dont you push them into one children array?

Comment: for comment `Comment 1-2` you have tow sub comments,then you should have `children` array with `Comment 1-2-1` and `Comment 1-2-2` in it.but what your data in fiddle is haveing two `children` properties.

Comment: i have a question, i tried your code,  why is it returning

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit. Please have a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/6dcdbks4/2/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var StmId = $('[name = "StatementId"]').val();
 var JsonArr = [{
                   "comment":"Comment 1", 
                   "commentID":1, 
                   "parentID":0,
                   "children":[{
                              "comment":"Comment 1-2", 
                              "commentID":2, 
                              "parentID":1, 
                              "children":[{
                                         "comment":"Comment 1-2-2",
                                         "commentID":1,
                                         "parentID":2 
                                         }]
                            }]
                },
                {
                "comment":"Comment 2", 
                "commentID":4, 
                "parentID":0
               }]

var commentsContainer = $("<div></div>");

showComments(JsonArr);

function loadComment(commentObj, commentsContainer, isChild){
   // console.log(commentObj);
    var profileFullName = "Full Name";
    var marginLeft = '';
    if ( commentObj.parentID > 0 ) {
         marginLeft = 'style="margin-left: '+commentObj.parentID*60+'px;"'
    }
    
    var commentHTML = '<div '+marginLeft+' class="commentbox"><div class="commentphoto"><a href="#123"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100000816365798/picture?type=square"></a></div><div class="commentcontent"><a href="#123"><strong>' + profileFullName + '</strong></a> &nbsp;<small>Just now</small><br>' + commentObj.comment + '<br><a name="replyComment" commentid="' + commentObj.commentID + '">Reply</a><span id="votescore-' + commentObj.commentID + '" class="votescore"></span></div></div>';
    commentsContainer.append(commentHTML);
       // console.log(commentsContainer.closest('.commentbox'));
    return commentsContainer;
}

function showComments(comments, isChild){
 for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
    // console.log(comments[i]['comment']);
       commentsContainer = loadComment(comments[i], commentsContainer, isChild)
    if (comments[i]['children'] && comments[i]['children'].length) {
      showComments(comments[i]['children'], true)
    }
  }
}

$('.commentbox').append(commentsContainer);
});
```